# How can I remove scratches from my mobile phone?

Tags: packaging

I have my smart phone without any protector and the condition of it's screen is very bad. It is full of scratches. Is there any hack so that I made clear my mobile screen?

Comment: Is there a reason that you do not get a screen protector for your phone and would rather go through the expense and effort of trying to repair yours now?

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to polish plastic, but [polishing glass takes many hours using progressively finer abrasives](http://www.bbastrodesigns.com/JoyOfMirrorMaking/Polishing.html).

That said, you might try covering the scratches with a plastic that approximately matches the index of refraction of the glass. [Kits](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EA5WLS) to do so are sold to repair chipped car windshields. Note that the repair is far from perfect: it may still leave visible scratches or lumps on the screes and will be more easily scratched, in the future, than glass.

If the screen is other than ordinary glass (e.g. sapphire or Gorilla© Glass), then neither polishing nor scratch-filler may be feasible, because of the hardness, surface finish or index of refraction of the screen.

Obviously, a clear screen protector can prevent this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your best option is to replace the screen.